# How to stop users from Switching to Root user

Tags: security, rhel, users, su, access-control

I have disabled the root user login from Sshd.conf file so now no one can login using root user even if they know the password SOMEHOW.

Now I have 3 users in server ROOT,EMERG and ORACLE. I want to allow switching to ROOT only to EMERG user by using su - and not to ORACLE user.

because normally if users know the ROOT password they can switch to root using su -. And i want this feature available only to EMERG user.

How to do this

Thanks in advance......

Comment: Have a look at `sudo` it allows much better and finer grained access control. Plus it can authenticate users with **their** passwords.

Comment: If my anser works for you, you may want to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 16):

`su` (mostly) uses pam for authentication and pam has a module called pam_wheel which checks group membership of the authenticating user. In short, by adding

```
auth       required   pam_wheel.so group=becomeroot
```

to the file `/etc/pam.d/su`, only users who are members of the group `becomeroot` may become root using su. Now you make sure only your user EMERG is a member of the group becomeroot. Some distros have/use the group named `wheel` for that.

```
groupadd becomeroot         #add the group becomeroot to your system
gpasswd -a EMERG becomeroot # add the user EMERG to the group becomeroot
```

Further reading:
pam (7)
pam_wheel (8)
groupadd (8)
gpasswd (1)
and many distros have explaining comments in `/etc/pam.d/su` as well

Comment: Not all distributions have a `wheel` group, or it could be named differently.