# Preventing other users from viewing my files

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, root, su, privacy

Ref: [Can root/superuser read my read-protected files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117150/can-root-superuser-read-my-read-protected-files)

My Ubuntu user account name "user-3121" with type as "Administrator". There is one more account named "admin" with type as "Administrator". How can I be sure whether or not "admin" can login as me or otherwise view my files in "user-3121"?

I discussed this with the other user and we have tried to modify `/etc/sudoers` to protect my files:

```
Cmnd_Alias   SHELLS = /bin/sh,/bin/bash,/bin/ksh, /usr/bin/x11/passwd

Cmnd_Alias   SU = /usr/bin/su,/bin/su,/usr/bin/gksudo,/usr/bin/sudo,/usr/bin/su bash,/usr/bin/sudo /bin/bash,/usr/sbin/visudo

Cmnd_Alias   PASS = /usr/bin/passwd root,/bin/* * root,/bin/* * sysadmin,/bin/* * /home/sysadmin,/usr/bin/passwd

Cmnd_Alias      EDIT= /bin/* /etc/sudoers,/bin/* sudoers,/bin/* /etc/passwd,/bin/* passwd,/bin/* /etc/group,/bin/* group,/bin/* /etc/shadow,/bin/* shadow,/*/*/[a-z]* /etc/sudoers,/*/*/[a-z]* /etc/passwd,/*/*/[a-z]* /etc/group,/*/*/[a-z]* /etc/shadow,/*/*/[a-z]* sudoers,/*/*/[a-z]* passwd,/*/*/[a-z]* group,/*/*/[a-z]* shadow

Cmnd_Alias   CMDS = /usr/sbin/userdel * sysadmin,/usr/sbin/userdel sysadmin,/usr/sbin/deluser * sysadmin,/usr/sbin/deluser sysadmin

root    ALL=(ALL) ALL, !CMDS

%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL, !SHELLS, !SU, !CMDS, !PASS, !EDIT
%sudo  ALL=(ALL) ALL,!SHELLS, !SU, !CMDS, !PASS, !EDIT

admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
administrator ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

If "admin" can still read my data, how do I prevent that?  Also how does this configuration work, it allows "user-3121" to run some sudo commands, but it doesn't actually mention "user-3121" anywhere?

P.S. I'm the only person who knows the password for the "root" user, so that I can log in as root using the "su" command.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/244297/can-users-in-a-group-access-a-file-that-is-in-another-users-home-directory

Comment: That isn't helpful, as I don't know what are all accessible by user "admin", and relate with sudoers.

Comment: It answers  "How do I know whether "admin" can login as me and view my files in "user-3121"?"

Comment: You aren't in sudoers because you didn't make yourself a sudoer. But you already have sudoer permissions since you are in the group admin.

Comment: If you want the other admin to not be able to access your files you'll need to change their permissions. If you are the only one with the root password just make a local sudoers file for "admin".

Comment: Or better yet, change the permissions of your home directory.

Comment: sudo chmod 0700 /home/user-3121

Comment: Ok, I get you. Now I logged in as user "admin", by "su - admin", and all my "user-3121"'s files are accessible. How can I just prevent access to my "user-3121" 's files, but not modifying anything else for "admin"? How do I do it in /etc/sudoers?

Comment: then take them out of the sudoers group. deluser admin sudo

Comment: actually tell me if just changing the permissions on your home directory works. I think they can still su you.

Comment: My thought is, prevent them from sudoing so they cant sudo su you. then take away their su permissions.

Comment: Yes, changing the permissions worked. But, how do I know whether "admin" can su "user-3121"? I am able to only login as "root" and then "su - admin" to get logged in as "admin". But, again to "su - user-3121", it asks for "admin" password. I don't know "admin" 's password.

Comment: lets move to chat...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop users from Switching to Root user](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62139/how-to-stop-users-from-switching-to-root-user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now I understand what this is saying

> ```
> Cmnd_Alias   CMDS = /usr/sbin/userdel * sysadmin, ...
> %admin ALL=(ALL) ALL, !SHELLS, !SU, !CMDS, !PASS, !EDIT
> ```

unfortunately it is a terrible idea.

In security, a general principle is you should be able to describe what you're *allowing*.  It's surprisingly rare to be able to make a list of what is *not* allowed, and be sure you haven't missed anything.

Specifically

```
$ cp /usr/sbin/userdel ./letsbefriends
$ sudo ./letsbefriends sysadmin
```

(and the same principle applies to a configuration which specifically blocks `sudo su` / `sudo sudo`).

As a postive example, consider this listing of *allowed* tasks for your "admin" user [*]:

```
# admin can run `reboot`.  (They can't run e.g. `reboot --force`).
admin ALL=(ALL) reboot ""
```

> Why [is] "user-3121" missing in /etc/sudoers?

Excellent question!  user-3121 is a member of the sudo *group*.  In `/etc/sudoers`, this group is matched by the line `%sudo`.

---

You might think "That's a cute hack you've showed me.  Surely I could think of a way to block that as well".  And there are approaches you could take.  But you would be arguing for the sake of it, and trying not to accept the general principle.

Someone else comes along, with a different idea.  What does this do? [**]

```
$ sudo /proc/self/exe sh
```

That's two different examples you would have to configure your system to block.  You can trust I know more.  *You* end up writing this complex custom configuration.  Complex systems inevitably include bugs.  Did you want to create a custom system, troubleshoot and maintain it?  Usually you want to try and work *with* the operating system you installed, so you can benefit from all the work that goes into developing, documenting and supporting it.

---

[*] In practice, limiting sudo to a certain purposes does tend to be more difficult than one might like. I expect it is not common to rely on sudo rules to provide a true security barrier.  Instead, it's used to delegate permission for specific tasks, while protecting users from themselves.  It reduces the chances of making a mistake and writing zeros all across their valuable hard drive, or the firmware on the network card.

[**] Spoiler:

`sudo /proc/self/exe sh` would run a shell as the root user.

It bypasses the blocklist defined as `SU`, using the same technique of running a command (sudo) using an alternative filename which is not on the blocklist.  So this second instance of `sudo` is successfully run as the `root` user.  The posted configuration allows the `root` user to run any command through `sudo`.  The second `sudo` instance is therefore allowed to run a shell as the root user.

The resulting shell can be used to run any command as `root`.  The shell does not use sudo, so it does not look at any lists of blocked commands in `sudoers`.  E.g. the shell could run `su` to log into a shell running as any given user, without knowing their password.

Comment: I recommend you merge both your answers into one answer (i.e. delete one and merge its text into the other) as they are essentially saying the same thing.  (You are completely correct; it is impossible to secure anything with a `sudo` blacklist.)

Comment: @sourcejedi A shell would not work here. If you look at the /etc/sudoers file you'll find that the sudo group does not have permissions to run a shell as root.

Comment: In my defense that "sudo blacklist" was not my idea, it was his admin's. But regardless your answer is wrong, he does not in fact have to "block" either of your approaches. Try it yourself, you will get "cannot execute XXX as root, sorry" errors.

Comment: But the "decide what to allow" approach is definitely better, you're right about that. Like iptables. One other thing, he does not have the permissions to use dd either.

Comment: '/proc/self/exe -i  won't work either, you'll get another "not allowed to xecute as root" error.

Comment: Anyway, if he were to put in the sudoers file only priviledges allowed, what ones would be allowed? The + does this.

Comment: What I'm trying to get at is I resent being called "some users", and my answer works. :/

Comment: @trudgemank you were not the only one as far as I could tell :). unix_root also asked "What if there are two administrator users? One can read another's files without password?", and then rejected my answer (which was in the positive).  How would you prefer I referred to the two of you? My instinct is not to call people out by name because that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @trudgemank if you're arguing neither of my approaches would bypass these blocks, then we should focus on the first one.  I'm not very interested in debugging / tracing a kilobyte of someone else's code, nor installing it on my system.  I'm not following your explanation.  It would be very helpful if you pointed out the specific configuration steps, that prevent the "admin" user from copying `userdel` or `sudo` to my home directory as `a-safe-command`, and then running `sudo ./a-safe-command` with whatever arguments they like.

Comment: @trudgemark I used ctrl+F to search this page for the `+` character.  The only instance I could find was your comment here.  So I don't understand how the `+` character is relevant to the configuration in the question (or the answers).  I provided an example of only allowing a specific command, it does not use the `+` character.

Comment: clarification: <del>to my home directory</del>: to their home directory

Comment: My "solution" is basically make the file 0700 and then nerf his priviledges. As for + I'm talking about how to add priviledges selectively in sudoers.list

Comment: @trudgemank Does this mean you want to request an edit for the answer you posted, to say that what you meant was to remove the "admin" user from any group listed in `sudoers`?  And remove "making sure only root has permissions to edit /etc/sudoers" because those lines don't help and can only confuse people?

Comment: In my case, "admin" was in %sudo group and also exists in sudoers as "admin ALL=(ALL) ALL". I deleted that line and also did "sudo deluser admin sudo". ^_^

Comment: @sourcejedi yeah, I kinda gave up on my answer. My philosophy is "do what I know and dont resort to google search". I play around and troubleshoot, sometimes this involves complicated yet not-so-efficient solutions. that's very naughty of your unix root! That's something no one has mentioned. Are you allowed to be doing this??!! Will your admin be po'd? Am I an accessory to a crime?

Comment: @sourcejedi You saw [this](http://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2017/05/30/16) exploit? This says `This allows any Sudoer user to obtain full root privileges`. I'm more confused now? You said that sudoers and root has same rights!? Am I missing something here?

Comment: If sudoers are designed actually to do everything that root can do, then what is the necessity of this exploit?

Comment: @unix_root I said no such thing.  I said I expected it is common for people to set up sudo rules, without expecting them to be completely secure against abuse.  I expect it's also common not to think about them too hard.  Or as in this question, to think about them for a long time and just get it flat wrong.  It's still theoretically possible to set up sudo rules which can't automatically be abused to provide root access.  E.g. allowing the use of `lprm` to delete print jobs from any user.  But you can't expect to do a wide range of sysadmin tasks through sudo, and not be root-equivalent.

Comment: // But you can't expect to do a wide range of sysadmin tasks through sudo, and not be root-equivalent. // But, a suoder can gain `root` by `sudo /proc/self/exe -i`. Now, he gained complete root, am I right? Can root prevent this escalation done by a sudoer?

Comment: @unix_root please actually read what I am saying.  How are you going to run `sudo /proc/self/exe -i` if the sudo configuration allows your user to run `/usr/sbin/lprm` with the arguments of your choice, but not any other command?

Comment: Uh, I forgot about that whitelisting commands thingy. I got it now. (Y)

Answer (score 1):

Easy, if it's an "administrator" type account then you should assume it can do anything.  (Example provided below)

(Also if a user has access to your boot loader menu, or firmware configuration interface aka BIOS setup screen).

If you can run commands of your choice under [user ID 0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser#Unix_and_Unix-like) (e.g. sudo), then you have essentially the same level of access as the process which installed your operating system in the first place.  Or as one of the [rescue disks](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=linux+rescue+disk) you could boot from - these are able to back up all your files, or migrate them from one drive to another for upgrade purposes, etc.

Without certain TPM software (which is not implemented on Ubuntu or similar), they could install a keylogger to capture your password, or disabling any authentication checks you implement.

*Per-user* encryption can prevent casual access.  Ubuntu community documentation last updated two years ago claims you can enable this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedHome

### Example file access

Apparently some users think e.g. `chmod 0700` protects your directories.  This is incorrect.  You might contrive situations where it works but it is not enough on its own.  Example running on Fedora Workstation 24, ext4 filesysem:

```
$ mkdir secret    # directory with "secret" contents
$ chmod 0700 secret    # apply access control
$ ls -ld secret    # show access control
drwx------. 2 alan-sysop alan-sysop 4096 Nov 13 20:31 secret
$ sudo -u nobody ls -l secret    # other user ("nobody") is denied access
[sudo] password for alan-sysop: 
ls: cannot access 'test': Permission denied
$ sudo ls -l secret    # but root user bypasses access controls (CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE)
total 0
```

Comment: What if there are two administrator users? One can read another's files without password?

Comment: Easy, if it's an "administrator" type account then you should assume it can do anything.

Comment: I guess that is wrong. That actually defeats basic security. Some reference may be helpful.

Comment: He only has the priviledges afforded in the sudoers page, so he cannot do everything. For instance, he cannot sudo su. Anyway this is really thorough. I don't think we're dealing with a boss who uses keyloggers

Comment: also I don't believe all those exceptions were necessary. just taking away his sudo rights should do it.

Comment: @unix_root I have improved my explanation, with reference to the capabilities of common boot discs.  What do you consider "basic security" once you're running commands of your choice as root?

Comment: Ahem, changing the permissions of the file was not all he did. The other user simply does not have the permissions for it. And he cannot change the permissions, because he does not have root access.

Comment: With "sudo", he can see anyone's files even though it has 0700.

Comment: that's not true. try it.

Comment: Tried in Ubuntu and Kali. It worked. Just do "sudo su -", and you'll be logged into root. Make sure, "root" account is enabled in Ubuntu. Also, I am able to view other "Administrator's" files with 0700 with just "sudo".

Answer (score 0):

Okay, summarizing the chat for anyone who has this question. Basically what he did is change permissions of his home directory to `0700` (only he can read write execute)

> chmod 0700 /homedirectory

Then the rest of the chat was trying to make sure that the admin couldn't `su` him or `sudo su` him. (Yes he could normally get the files in other ways but he doesn't have the permissions.) This entails changing the permissions given in `/etc/sudoers` and making sure only `root` has permissions to edit `/etc/sudoers`.

Comment: This worked only when "admin" don't have sudoers rights. Else, "admin" can run "sudo su - user-3121" and enter admin's password and happily su'ed user-3121. So, only way to prevent "admin" to see user-3121's files is to remove him from sudoers list.

Comment: Also, note that, doing "sudo deluser admin sudo" from root has no use. You have to manually change "admin ALL=(ALL) ALL" to "admin ALL=(ALL) ALL, !SU" in /etc/sudoers. (Refer !SU alias code in the question - revoke su binaries to admin)

Comment: (to be explicit, controlling su doesn't help either, sudo already gives you [CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html)

Comment: How about this: admin ALL=(ALL) ALL, !SHELLS, !SU, !CMDS, !PASS, !EDIT Can "admin" su me with his password (without my password)?

Comment: oh, you're giving admin the same priviledges as admin group? He can't su you but I'm afraid he'll be annoyed if you change his permissions...

Comment: but its kind of funny. you're giving him the priviledges he gave you :)

Comment: I'll try again.  admin doesn't need to su to you.  admin can run sudo commands, which have the capability to view (or change) all your files.  The "login as me" part doesn't really matter.

Comment: sudo doesn't have root permissions on his computer. they are different. he can only do those things as root. he knows because he tried viewing admins files with sudo, he can't. just with root, and admin can't sudo su

Comment: @sourcejedi How can he view my files with just sudo, if I have 0700 file permissions?

Comment: @unix_root by viewing your files with sudo.  For a worked example please see new section "Example file access" of my answer.

Comment: Oh my. So, basically sudo is pure "root" permission. -_-

Comment: by default it is. but your sudo is not. did you read his sudoers file? ALL,!SHELLS, !SU, !CMDS, !PASS, !EDIT <<<< he can't do all of that stuff. sudo is basically equivalent to admin priviledges.

Comment: @trudgemank what does this last sentence mean? You're saying there's something called admin privileges, which is something different from "pure root"? What is this concept of admin privileges, where can I learn what it means (where in the code or documentation or community documentation / support messages)?

Comment: @trudgemank, if you have "sudo" rights, you can do everything "root" can.

Comment: look at the sudoers.list. "sudo" group has the same priviledges as "admin" group. and yes, sudo can do everything root can by default, but your admin changed it so that it doesn't have root permissions

Comment: No, it doesn't work that way. That's what @sourcejedi said. Blacklisting can always be bypassed with just "sudo" capability. Just copy /bin/su to your home as "./sutemp", and execute it to login as root.  "sudo ./sutemp -" will do it, where sutemp is copied from /bin/su to your pwd as "sutemp". FYI, I am able to login as "root" from user-3121, with just my password. The same sudoers file in the question is used.

Comment: Oy. sourcejedi is more learned than I but apparently less perspicacious. Look at your sudoers list. looks at roots priviledges. now look at the sudo group. they are different. so sudo cannot do everything root can, try it yourself (I did). sj is talking about sudo by default. your admin changed its priviledges.

Comment: I tried what you mentioned. No permission to execute the script as I thought. I don't know why it's not working for me :/ It may have been some security thing I set up and forgot about.